# Rails send_data excel works in firefox but not IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, download, export-to-excel

This is my action:

```
def report
  spreadsheet = StringIO.new
  [%w(o hai)].dump_to_excel(spreadsheet)

  send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename=> "#{f.name}.xls", 
    :type=> "application/vnd.ms-excel"
end
```

I use [spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) and [this code](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1249-dump-a-two-dimensional-array-to-an-excel-xls-spreadsheet) to generate an excel file on the fly and send it for download.

When report's link (domain/report/id) is clicked in firefox on linux and windows, the file is downloaded. When it is clicked in windows with IE 6, it says:

Internet explorer cannot download `<id>` from `<domain>`

I was informed that IE9 also doesn't work.

I tried dispatch attachment, application/xls mime type, didn't help.

How do you send excel binary for internet explorer to download on rails?

Comment: have you tried adding a `:disposition => :attachment`?

Comment: @EladMeidar I tried :disposition=> "attachment", I forgot to type it in the question

Comment: Did you try with other file types? I bet MS has some special treatment of Office attachments in IE and you have to have special headers.